# ProjectOxford emotion recognition

Tags: c#, exception, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying Microsoft Emotion Recognition with OpenCV face detection. Everithing is fine until 
`Emotion[] emotions = await client.RecognizeAsync(pstream, face_rects);`
This throws `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.ClientException` with no info in it.

Api keys is up to date and must be working. Does anyone have same problem?

**Update:**

I found out. There where no image header at `pstream`. Now there is error code `InvalidImageSize`, it says that image size is too small or too big.

And now I am saving image with

`Bitmap::Save( Stream, ImageFormat );`

Comment: You can find more information about what went wrong in `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.ClientException.Error.Message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you have answered this yourself, but for the sake of other people looking for the answer, I'll re-provide it here.

Make sure your image that is used in `pstream` has a header and it is within the accepted size dimensions for the api.